# Вызов метода в конкретное время по графику (by schedule)

Tags: c#, schedule, таймер

Как вызывать метод в конкретное время каждый день или же одноразово?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Проблема вызова метода по расписанию не решается в общем виде. Дело в том, что в нужное время ваша программа может вовсе не работать!

Поэтому, для начала, требуется придумать способ запуска программы по этому самому расписанию.

Тут возможны три варианта:

1. Планировщик Windows. Иногда кажется, что про него забыли - но он со временем становится только лучше. И если на том же XP администратор часто выключал планировщик - то в последних версиях винды он обычно все же оставлен включенным, потому что на него завязано много полезных программ и служб.

   Подробнее про создание задачи в планировщике windows можно увидеть тут: [Creating Scheduled Tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7394955/4340086)
2. SQL Server Agent. Если вы используете SQL Server (а его использует довольно много проектов) - то и его агент будет где-то рядом. Процедура создания задачи описана [на MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190268.aspx#TsqlProcedure) (там используются хранимые процедуры - то есть вам понадобится подключение к БД и права администратора сервера).

---

В обоих случаях, вам будет нужен какой-то способ вызвать не программу целиком, а конкретный метод. Для этого можно:

- Выбирать метод для вызова исходя из аргументов командной строки. Тут может помочь пакет [CommandLineParser](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CommandLineParser/2.1.1-beta) из nuget.
- Использовать powershell. Поскольку powershell основан на CLR, из него можно обращаться к любым методам на C#:

  ```
  Add-Type -Path путь\к\сборке.dll
  [Ваш.Класс]::СтатическийМетод(Параметры)
  ```

  SQL Server Agent может вызвать встроенный powershell-скрипт, а планировщику windows будет нужен отдельный файл, лежащий на диске.

  Также, вероятно, вам придется обработать событие `AppDomain.AssemblyResolve` чтобы загрузить зависимые сборки.

---

3. Можно написать свою службу, которая будет запущена все время и выполнять задачи. В этом случае вам может пригодиться библиотека [Quartz.NET](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/). Или же можно "накатать" свой велосипед (там основа - просто `Thread.Sleep` или `Task.Delay` в бесконечном цикле).

   В любом случае, основная проблема тут будет - хранение списка задач в каком-то постоянном хранилище (БД) или восстановление этого списка при запуске службы.

   Способ с хранением в БД больше подойдет для задач, создаваемых пользователем, а способ с восстановлением при запуске - для задач, определяемых настройками приложения.

Comment: Хороший ответ. Дополню, что службы неплохо ещё писать с использованием nuget-пакета Topshelf.

Comment: @AK ой, а что так сложно у них все?