# Выполнение операций по расписанию

Tags: c#, .net, планировщик-задач

Необходимо проводить определенные действия по расписанию, *абстрактный* пример:

- в **понедельник** в 12:00 взять файлы из папки
- во **вторник** в 13:39 создать папку с файлами
- в **третью пятницу** в 7:03 посчитать количество файлов

Целесообразно ли будет для этого использовать `timer` с `Interval` в минуту и в его `Tick` проверять время и день недели?

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var currentTime = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
   var currentDow = DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;
   var oneMinute = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);
   if ((currentDow  == DayOfWeek.Monday)&&(currentTime-timeMonday<oneMinute))
   {
      MondayOperation();  
   }

   if ((currentDow  == DayOfWeek.Tuesday)&&(currentTime-timeTuesday<oneMinute))
   {
      TuesdayOperation();  
   }

   if ((currentDow  == DayOfWeek.Friday)&&(MyDoWInMonth(DateTime.Now).Equals(3))&(currentTime-timeFriday<oneMinute))
   {
      FridayOperation();  
   }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Нет, этого совершенно недостаточно. Windows не дает никаких гарантий, что ваш таймер и правда будет вызываться каждую минуту. С такими сравнениями вы запросто 
пропустите нужное время или отработаете два раза.

Более правильно будет хранить для каждой задачи следующее время запуска и запускать задачу когда текущее время больше запланированного (но не вышло за пределы некоторого разумного интервала). Про строгие сравнения времени забудьте в принципе!

---

PS для справки - мой старый ответ на смежную тематику: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/593736/178779

Answer (score 9):

Лучше используйте библиотеку [Quartz.net](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/), она специально предназначена для таких целей и очень гибко настраивается. Также она есть в nuget:

`Install-Package Quartz`

Либо можно вообще воспользоваться средствами планировщика задач Windows.

Answer (score 6):

[Hangfire](http://hangfire.io/) — планировщик задач для .NET

На мой взгляд это самый лучший многопоточный и масштабируемый планировщик задач.
Легкая установка с помощью NuGet

```
Install-Package Hangfire
```

С коробки есть красивый дашборд со всей статистикой и всеми запланированными заданиями.

Краткий обзор на [habrahabr](https://habrahabr.ru/post/280732/)

Answer (score 5):

Я бы разделил программу на 3 модуля и использовал бы стандартный Windows Task Scheduler. Тестировать будет удобнее + всегда понятно, какой компонент работает неверно

Answer (score 5):

Можете посмотреть в сторону `TopShelf` +  `Quartz`, очень удобно + есть всё что нужно (модули для DI, планирование как угодно).

Для этого Вам нужно будет разделить работы (создать классы производные от `IJob`), потом описать механизм планирования например так:

```
private static void ScheduleRepeatableJobIn**<T>(ServiceConfigurator<Service> serviceConfigurator, int timeout) where T : IJob
{
  serviceConfigurator.ScheduleQuartzJob(configurator =>
    configurator.WithSimpleRepeatableSchedule<T>(TimeSpan.From**(timeout), typeof(T).Name));
}
```

И потом просто запустить сервис/консоль так:

```
  HostFactory.Run(x =>
      {
        x.Service<Service1>(s =>
        {
          ScheduleRepeatableJobInMinutes<Job1>(s, timeout);
          ScheduleRepeatableJobInMinutes<Job2>(s, timeout);

          s.WhenStarted(tc => tc.Start());
          s.WhenStopped(tc => tc.Stop());
        });
      });
```

P.S. Пример кода показательный, для решение Вашей проблемы Вам нужно будет написать свою логику планирования.