# Функция по расписанию

Tags: c#, время, datetime

Есть два массива с временем(start[8:00, 8:50, 9:50], stop[8:40, 9:30, 10:30])

Как сделать так, чтобы при запуске программы мы получали текущее время и смотрели входит ли оно в временной промежуток, если да то мы выполняем функцию. Как можно подобное реализовать

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Выполнение операций по расписанию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/621148/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8e)

Comment: Пишете цикл по вашему массиву. Каждую итерацию в цикле выполняйте вашу функцию, после чего считайте время до следующего выполнения и ожидайте это время с помощью `Thread.Sleep` или `Task.Delay`. Ну, или запускайте одноразовый таймер и в конце каждого запуска планируйте следующий запуск

Comment: Ну и непонятно для чего вам нужен массив `stop`, на что он влияет?

Comment: @tym32167, очевидно пара элементов start stop составляет интервал

Comment: @Grundy интервал чего? Например, если время выполнения функции - 1 минута, её в этом интервале сколько раз вызывать? Как попасть в интервал? Нало вначале интервала вызывать функцию? Надо её стопать если функция долго играет и превысила интервал? Столько вопросов и мало ответов )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё очень просто. Если вы используете GUI приложение, то цикл формируете на DispatcherTimer с периодом срабатывания в 1 секунду (к примеру). Для консольного приложения можно использовать Thread.

И каждую итерацию цикла проверяете флаг состояния вашей задачи (IDLE, WORK). Для каждого состояния свой обработчик (по смыслу схож) который проверяет наличие вхождения в текущее значение времени и вызывает срабатывания действия stop() или start().

Как сравнивать? Парсите ваш массив с временем начала и окончания, разбивая строку на часы и минуты. Далее берёте текущее значение даты и сравниваете часы и минуты, до первого вхождения. При вхождении меняете флаг и изменяете состояние вашей задачи.

В итоге получается простой программируемый триггер.